# "Big cities will be growing or will have grown by then."

Tags: future-tense

Big cities will be growing or will have grown by then. In this sentence we use future continuous or future perfect simple.

Comment: Could you say what you think is correct and why, please?

Comment: Is there are particular question being asked here?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. "will be growing", and "will have grown" mean different things, but both are correct. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are trying to express.  There are two possibilities, and the different tenses express those situations:

- If the cities will be growing in the year 2050, you say *The cities will be growing in 2050.*
- If the cities will be bigger in 2050, *The cities will have grown by then(2050).*